# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
resp = urlopen('http://international.o2.co.uk/internationaltariffs 
/getintlcallcosts?countryId=IND').read()
crawler = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
div = crawler.find('div', {"id": "standardRates"})
div
```

[image]

With the above code it lists all the tags/elements you can see in the image. I want to get the "£2.00". Except when i call .find('td') again as follows:

```
div = crawler.find('div', {"id": "standardRates"}).find('td')
```

it only returns Landline and not the line below, even though it has the same tag. I have very little experience in web scraping. How can i target this tag (the line with the £2.00)?

Comment: try `findAll()` instead of just `find()`

Comment: `.findAll('td')[1]` to be exact

Comment: Great that worked. Although the results are a list so when I use .contents the string is surrounded by square brackets. Can i get it so it is just a string?

Comment: This is the line of code now: div = crawler.find('div', {"id": "standardRates"}).findAll('td')[1].contents  and it returns ['£2.00']

Comment: im just using .join it's not that elegant but does the job. Thanks for your helpful replies!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach to go fairly directly to the previous sibling of £2.00.

First find the desired table, then find the `td` with `Landline` in it as a string. Then get the parent of this `td`, get the next sibling of this, and finally get the next sibling.

```
>>> import requests
>>> get = requests.get('http://international.o2.co.uk/internationaltariffs/getintlcallcosts?countryId=IND')
>>> page = get.text
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
>>> Landline_td = soup.find('table', {'id': 'standardRatesTable'}).find_all(string='Landline')[0]
>>> Landline_td
'Landline'
>>> Landline_td.findParent().findNextSibling()
<td>£2.00</td>
>>> Landline_td.findParent().findNextSibling().text
'£2.00'
```